# Conditionally position labels on y axis

Tags: d3.js

I have a horizontal bar graph with positive and negative values. I would like to position the labels on the y axis to the left of the axis when the value is positive and to the right of the axis when the value is negative.

```
{value: -70, dataset:"foo"},
{value: -20, dataset:"bar"},
{value: 30, dataset:"baz"}
etc...
```

The value of the first bar is negative and the label `foo` is on the right side of the axis, which is where I want it. But the value of the third bar is positive, so I would like to see that label on the left of the y axis. Is this possible?

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Kavitha_2817/fmr1x1gu/18/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution (out of many) is calling two axis generators, `axisLeft` and `axisRight`, and formatting the ticks according to the dataset values:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
    .call(d3.axisRight(y).tickFormat(function(d) {
        var value = data.filter(function(e) {
            return e.dataset === d
        })[0].value;
        return value > 0 ? null : d;
    }));

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis left")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(function(d) {
        var value = data.filter(function(e) {
            return e.dataset === d
        })[0].value;
        return value < 0 ? null : d;
    }));
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 10,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 500,
  height = 300;

var data = [{
  value: -10,
  dataset: "barbaz"
}, {
  value: 40,
  dataset: "barbar"
}, {
  value: -10,
  dataset: "foobaz"
}, {
  value: -50,
  dataset: "foobar"
}, {
  value: 30,
  dataset: "baz"
}, {
  value: -20,
  dataset: "bar"
}, {
  value: -70,
  dataset: "foo"
}];

// Add svg to
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right).attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom).append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

// set the ranges
var y = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([height, 0])
  .padding(0.1);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, width]);

// Scale the range of the data in the domains
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.value;
}));
y.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.dataset;
}));

// append the rectangles for the bar chart
svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return "bar bar--" + (d.value < 0 ? "negative" : "positive");
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(Math.min(0, d.value));
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.dataset);
  })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return Math.abs(x(d.value) - x(0));
  })
  .attr("height", y.bandwidth());

// add the x Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// add the y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
  .call(d3.axisRight(y).tickFormat(function(d) {
    var value = data.filter(function(e) {
      return e.dataset === d
    })[0].value;
    return value > 0 ? null : d;
  }));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis left")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(function(d) {
    var value = data.filter(function(e) {
      return e.dataset === d
    })[0].value;
    return value < 0 ? null : d;
  }));
```

```css
.bar--positive {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar--negative {
  fill: darkorange;
}

.y.axis.left {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @user1608142 if you use this approach, remember to delete one of the axes' path, otherwise you will have two lines one over the other.

Comment: If a property was added to the objects in the data array, say for example, 'description', would it be possible to add those properties as labels to the y axis, aligned to the far left side of the page, or perhaps concatenated to the dataset values?

Comment: As this is a different issue, please post another question.

Comment: As far as deleting one of the axes' path, would this be the correct way to do it: at the end of the call statement add .select("path.line").remove